# How to find import name/key of pip3 installed module

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pip, python-module

I am aware of how to install new python modules with pip. I have great success with that. But once the modules are installed, I have no idea how to import them.

For example, I may run

```
sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

I see all of the necessary install messages, and I am told that my brand spanking new module has been installed. I run pip3's list and freeze functions, and sure enough, it says that the modules are installed. My pip3 freeze output looks like...

```
mysql-connector-python==1.1.6
```

I then run python 3.xx and try

```
import mysql-connector-python
```

thinking that text listed in my pip3 freeze call is the import path, but I get an ImportError.

Is there a way to list the keys/keywords/strings that I need to use to properly import a new module? Clearly, mysql-connector-python is not the right key. That's really all I need, the keyword. After that, I can do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the files an installed package contains using:

```
pip show --files packagename
```

The base directory that features prominently in that list will in most cases be the package name to import inside Python.

Comment: I looked a little more into what's returned by this, and it seems to output what is in the `installed-files.txt`, which is in the `-info` folder that usually comes with the package.
There also seems to be a `top_level.txt` file, which has the folder name, which is usually the keyword I need. Is there a way to have pip return that? Or should I just do some os module finagiling?

Comment: @PeterWalker, can't see a way to get pip to return that.

Comment: Ah well, thanks for looking into it. The `--files` did help me a lot though. Thanks!